# iOS Push notification through AWS SNS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

iOS Push notification through AWS SNS.
Payload getting displayed inside iOS devices notification panel instead of message.

ex :

```
{
    "default": "Sample message",
    "APNS": {
        "aps": {
            "alert": {
                "body": "You have new message",
                "title": "Sample message"
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you kept `aps` inside `APNS`.

As per the apple documentation, the payload should be like this,

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Game Request",
            "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
            "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
        },
        "badge" : 5
    },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : [ "bang",  "whiz" ]
}
```

Note: "aps" should be available directly in the keys, you should not enclose it inside other values.

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1),

Comment: According to the SNS payload the "aps" should be inside the "APNS" or "APNS_SANDBOX" key.